# Highlight all possible circles ( Bubble sheet choices ) in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am working on automatically correcting a bubble-sheet tests that are scanned.
Currently, I can extract the solutions part of the sheet and fix its rotation.

So I have this image.
[image: The input image]

The output image with detected contours
[image: The output image]

Running the following code yields in the output image

```
def get_answers(image):
    display_normal("Just image",image)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurry = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 1)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blurry, 225, 255,
                       cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

    display_normal("Binary", thresh)
    # find contours in the thresholded image, then initialize
    # the list of contours that correspond to questions
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[1]

    questionCnts = []

    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        # compute the bounding box of the contour, then use the
        # bounding box to derive the aspect ratio
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ar = w / float(h)

        # in order to label the contour as a question, region
        # should be sufficiently wide, sufficiently tall, and
        # have an aspect ratio approximately equal to 1
        if w >= 18 and h >= 18 and 0.9 <= ar and ar <= 1.2:
            questionCnts.append(c)


    cv2.drawContours(image, questionCnts, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
    display_normal("Image with contours",image.copy())
    if(questionCnts < 45*4):
        raise Exception("Didn't found all possible answers")
```

Here is the problem : I convert the input image to binary and try to find contours that looks like a circle, but I can't find the whole possible 45*4 choices.. I fail to detect some of these circles..

So is there any better idea/algorithm to do this specific task ?

Comment: if you know the sizes of the circle grid you can automatically check whether any circles are not detected. Correct those sheets by hand if not too many. In general I would suggest some adaptive thresholding and/or edge detection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have tried using **adaptive threshold**:

```
adapt_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(equ, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
cv2.imshow('adapt_thresh.jpg', adapt_thresh)
```

[image]

(I resized the original image to keep it smaller)

**UPDATE:**

Another approach that I just performed.......

I equalized the gray scale image using **histogram equalization**:

```
equalized_img =  cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
cv2.imshow('Equalized Image.jpg', equalized_img )
```

[image]

I then obtained the **median** of the equalized image using `np.median(equalized_img)` and applied a binary threshold by selecting all pixel values below **[0.6 * median]**

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(equalized_img, lower, 255, 1)
cv2.imwrite("Final Image.jpg", thresh)
```

[image]

Now you can go ahead and find your desired contours on this image.

Hope it helps  .. :)